# XSL 1.0 - How to use for-each over a tokenized string

Tags: xslt, foreach, xslt-1.0, tokenize

Using XSL 1.0, I found a nice tokenize function. Now I need to for-each over the resulting tokens. I am very new to XSL.

The php equivalent of what I need:

```
$in = 'a,b,c,d';
$tokens = explode (',', $in);
foreach ($tokens as $token) {
  echo $token;
}
```

Here's what I have so far. This line will output 'a,b,c,d'-

```
<xsl:value-of select="@CommaSeparated" />
```

This will run that string through the tokenize function-

```
  <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="@CommaSeparated"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
```

And the tokenize function. I understand what this does, just not the format of the data it spits out-

```
<xsl:template name="tokenize">
  <xsl:param name="pText"/>

  <xsl:if test="string-length($pText)">
    <tag>
      <xsl:value-of select=
       "substring-before($pText, ',')"/>
    </tag>

    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
      <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
       "substring-after($pText, ',')"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Are you asking if XSLT supports for-each? Yes it does - `xsl:for-each`, thoguh it's best avoided in favour of template assignment, where possible.

Comment: For the record, what I ended up doing is writing several Tokenize-like functions that would do the split and output. So the template 'Tokenize_Links' would take 'a,b,c' and output '<a>a</a>, <a>b</a>, etc'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the tokenize function are using is not actually correct. In theory, it should spit out a list of **tag** elements (strictly speaking a "result tree fragment") like so

```
<tag>a</tag>
<tag>b</tag>
<tag>c</tag>
<tag>d</tag>
```

But it is actually missing out the last element

```
<tag>a</tag>
<tag>b</tag>
<tag>c</tag>
<tag></tag>
```

You are probably better off finding another tokenize function here (there must be surely working ones here in StackOverflow).

But, in answer your question about using xsl:for-each over this, you might be tempted to do something like this...

```
  <xsl:variable name="tags">
    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
       <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="@CommaSeparated"/>
     </xsl:call-template> 
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:for-each select="$tags/tag">
     <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:for-each>
```

That is to say, store the list of tags in a variable, and then loop over them. However, if you try this in XSLT1.0 you would get an error "Expression must evaluate to a node-set.". To get around this, you need to use an extension function. EXSLT is probably the most common. You would declare this in your XSLT like so

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">
```

You could them simply change the **xsl:for-each** as follows:

```
<xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($tags)/tag">
```

So, given the following XML

```
<a CommaSeparated="a,b,c,d"></a>
```

And the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/a">
        <xsl:variable name="tags">
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="@CommaSeparated"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($tags)/tag">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:param name="pText"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($pText)">
            <tag>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pText, ',')"/>
            </tag>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, ',')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The following is output (with the last tag blank due to the bugged tokenize function you are using)

```
<tag>a</tag>
<tag>b</tag>
<tag>c</tag>
<tag></tag>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Sadly, that defective Tokenize function IS one I found on StackOverflow.

Comment: Have a look at this question, which is asking more or less the same thing, and has a tokenize functiont that works! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425071/split-function-in-xslt-1-0

Answer (score 0):

Check this code :

```
<xsl:variable name="val">
       <xsl:value-of select="@CommaSeparated"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[ ]]></xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/a">
    <xsl:variable name="tags">
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$val"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($tags)/tag">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="pText"/>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($pText)">
        <tag>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pText, ',')"/>
        </tag>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, ',')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The opening remark of "Check this code" could be asking a question or it could be saying here is an example. If it is a question then it should not be written as an answer. If it really is an answer then it would be helpful to says so and also to explain how it solves the original question.