# How to split and break string in new line in XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a string like

```
*this is text1 * this is text2 *this is text3
```

I want the output by spliting the text using * in my pdf like

```
this is text1 
this is text2 
this is text3
```

my text coming in @value of xslt like

```
     <fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve" > 
         <xsl:value-of select="@key"/>
             </fo:block>
                <fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve" > 
              <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                </fo:block>
            <fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve" > 
                 <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
             </fo:block>
    </fo:block>
```

How can I split the string produce the output. Please suggest. I'm using xsl 1.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [split function in xslt 1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425071/split-function-in-xslt-1-0)

Comment: The simplest solution is using XSLT 2.0, with the `tokenize()` function. If you can't use XSLT 2.0, then you will either need to write a template yourself (which might not be trivial as you are new to XSLT) or use extensions such as EXSLT. In the linked question you have examples of *all* those alternatives: EXSLT (solution using node-set and links to examples with tokenize), XSLT 2.0 and even a full named template. If they are confusing, you should read a bit about named templates and extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First call a template which performs the splitting for you instead of the `value-of`:

```
<xsl:call-template name="split">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@value"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Here is the named template:

```
<xsl:template name="split">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>

    <xsl:if test="string-length($text) > 0">
        <xsl:variable name="output-text">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before(concat($text, '*'), '*'))"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:if test="normalize-space($output-text) != ''">
            <xsl:value-of select="$output-text"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:call-template name="split">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '*')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Input (value of the `@value`):

```
*this is text1 * this is text2 *this is text3
```

Output:

```
this is text1
this is text2
this is text3
```