# Equivalent of tokenize in xsl 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

How to write the folowing in xsl 1.0

```
<xsl:template match="bulletin1 | bulletin2" name="tokenize">
  <xsl:param name="separator" select="','"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,$separator)">
  <td align="center" style="padding: 0em 0em 0.1em; text-align: left; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.3em; font-family: Georgia, Times, serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal;" valign="top" width="30%">
    &#8226;&#160;<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/><br /></td>
  </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: See (for example): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508030/take-the-value-next-to-the-last-in-xslt/38509740#38509740

Comment: Possible duplicate of [split function in xslt 1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425071/split-function-in-xslt-1-0)

Comment: this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425071/split-function-in-xslt-1-0

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions already out there. See comments!
Exactly for your example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template name="split" match="bulletin1 | bulletin2">
        <xsl:param name="input" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="seperator" select="','"/>

        <xsl:if test="string-length($input) > 0">
            <td align="center" style="padding: 0em 0em 0.1em; text-align: left; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.3em; font-family: Georgia, Times, serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal;" valign="top" width="30%">
                &#8226;&#160;<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat(normalize-space($input), $seperator), $seperator)"/><br /></td>

            <xsl:call-template name="split">
                <xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring-after($input, $seperator)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

for sample-xml like:

```
<document>
    <bulletin1>abc,def</bulletin1>
    <bulletin2>1,2,3</bulletin2>
</document>
```

Comment: Throws error. xsl:param is not a recognized element

Comment: How do you execute the XSL? In an IDE, Browser, command-line? *It is a valid XSLT 1.0*