# Split the string by commas and insert <br> in place of commas in xslt

Tags: xml, email, xslt

I have a xslt template with a parameter string Test that contains ';' in it.
I want to change those ; and insert line break into the string which i will use as email body.
Below is the template:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>    
    <xsl:param name="Test"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <br/>
                Test: <xsl:value-of select="$Test"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is it possible to do in XSLT?

Comment: Which XSLT processor will you be using?

Comment: Do you actually want to insert a line break, or do you want to insert an html `<br>` tag?

Comment: Also, your title says `commas`, but your description uses `;` (semicolons)...  Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **yes, it is possible to split a string on some given delimiter, and replace that delimiter with something else.**

The longer answer is **yes, it is possible, but the best approach depends on what version of XSLT you can use.**

**XSLT 1.0** will likely require some combination of the following XPath functions:

```
substring-before()
substring-after()
```

... as well as recursion (calling the same template from itself) to ensure that you replace *all* instances of your chosen delimiter.

**XSLT 2.0** and later allows you to use the `tokenize()` function, making it possible to replace all instances of your delimiter without template recursion.

The structure of the full XSLT code is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score -1):

I've made a template that is met for doing this.

I recursively call it every time with a substring of the string after the ;
And every time it gets called it prints the part of the string before the first; until the last one.

Your string has to end with a ; or it won't be printed. But you can edit it to a template what does of course

```
<xsl:template name="insertLinebreaks">
    <xsl:param name="pText"/>

    <xsl:if test="contains($pText, ';')">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pText, ';')">
        <br />
        <xsl:call-template name="insertLinebreaks">
            <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, ';')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: `<xsl:text>&lt;br /&gt;</xsl:text>` Why? Why not simply `<br/>`?

Comment: I've had some trouble with it in the past. My IDE gave me a warning so I changed it to the &gt; and &lt; to be sure it works on every XSLT processor

Comment: Both work on every XSLT processor. But the result is different: one produces an HTML element, the other a useless string.

Comment: "*Your string has to end with a ; or it won't be printed.*" This has been solved a long time ago, and there are many examples showing the solution. (for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508030/take-the-value-next-to-the-last-in-xslt/38509740#38509740) There is really no need to post an inferior suggestion like that.

Comment: That's not true, it will return a <br /> tag.
And I'm just mentioning that with this template the last substring only gets printed when it ends with a ; there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Your right. My mistake, but try it with the <br /> tag. That won't work either. The thing I was remembering about was this: <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> &#60;br /&#62;</xsl:text> . This does work. Sorry, my mistake

Comment: "*but try it with the <br /> tag. That won't work either.*" Why wouldn't it? http://xsltransform.net/a9Gix5/1

Comment: In the <xsl:text> element. I thought that was what you meant with using the <br /> tag. Using the <br/> tag is the better solution. I try to use the <xsl:text> tag as much as I can so my spacing won't be affected in the output. But as I see from your code I shouldn't be that afraid of it.