# Query parameter manipulation

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an URL where having query parameter need to pick one particular value out of it.

Ex: /abc/xyz?gcode=123456&pcode=21314u925

Need to pick this value (gcode=123456) 
I used condition like below

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($currentURI,'?gcode='),'&amp;pcode=')"/>
```

The issue is in URI the order of the query parameter is not always gcode and followed by pcode. after gcode it can have any other parameter.

How can i get that value

Answer (score 1):

My first thoughts are that you should go try implement that sequence or something similar:

- get string your parameters (you can use substring after '/abc/xyz?'
- use tokenize function ( to get list of parameters )
- get element of list which contains gcode

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425071/split-function-in-xslt-1-0) your can get some sample how to use tokenize in xslt 1.0 or xslt 2.0

I hope that can help you at solving your problem

Answer (score 0):

An XSLT-1.0 solution can use an `xsl:choose` to handle both possibilities:

1. Another parameter follows
2. `gcode=` is the last parameter in the string

So some code could look like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="tmp" select="substring-after($currentURI,'gcode=')" />
<xsl:variable name="GCODE">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($tmp,'&amp;')">  <!-- other parameters do follow -->
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($tmp,'&amp;')" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>                           <!-- last parameter -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$tmp" />   
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="$GCODE" />                  <!-- Value of parameter = '123456' -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close with your attempt. What I would do is:

- drop the `?` from `?gcode=`
- change `&amp;pcode=` to just `&amp;`
- add a concat to add a trailing `&amp;` just in case `gcode` is the last query param

example...

```
<xsl:value-of 
 select="substring-before(concat(substring-after($currentURI,'gcode='),'&amp;'),'&amp;')"/>
```

You could also use a named template (XSLT 1.0+) or an xsl:function (XSLT 2.0+) if you need to get the value of a query param more than once.

Examples...

**XML Input**

```
<tests>
    <test><![CDATA[/abc/xyz?gcode=123456&pcode=21314u925]]></test>
    <test><![CDATA[/abc/xyz?pcode=21314u925&gcode=123456]]></test>
    <test>/abc/xyz?gcode=123456&amp;pcode=21314u925</test>
    <test>/abc/xyz?pcode=21314u925&amp;gcode=123456</test>
</tests>
```

**XSLT 1.0** (fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWVm)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="test">
    <xsl:variable name="currentURI" select="."/>
    <gcode>
      <xsl:call-template name="get-param">
        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'gcode'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="uri" select="$currentURI"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </gcode>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="get-param">
    <xsl:param name="name"/>
    <xsl:param name="uri"/>
    <xsl:value-of 
      select="substring-before(concat(
      substring-after($uri, concat($name,'=')),'&amp;'),
      '&amp;')"/>    
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 2.0** (fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWVm/1)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:l="local" exclude-result-prefixes="l xs">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="l:get-param">
    <xsl:param name="name" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="uri" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:value-of 
      select="substring-before(concat(
      substring-after($uri,concat($name,'=')),'&amp;'),
      '&amp;')"/>    
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="test">
    <xsl:variable name="currentURI" select="."/>
    <gcode>
      <xsl:value-of select="l:get-param('gcode',$currentURI)"/>
    </gcode>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output** (from either stylesheet above)

```
<tests>
   <gcode>123456</gcode>
   <gcode>123456</gcode>
   <gcode>123456</gcode>
   <gcode>123456</gcode>
</tests>
```