# XSLT 1.0: Substring multiple values

Tags: xml, substring, xslt-1.0

I have the following element and value:

**XML:**

```
<Location>Wing: ; Room: A; Bed: NAH; Group: 195;</Location>
```

I'm trying to sub string each value to it's own element.

**My Current XSLT:**

```
<PL.1>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(//Location, ' ; Room:')" />
</PL.1>
<PL.2>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(//Location, 'Bed:')" />
</PL.2>
<PL.3>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(//Location, 'Group:')" />
</PL.3>
<PL.4>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(//Location, 'Group:')" />
</PL.4>
```

The expected result that I'm going for is the following:

```
<PL.1>Wing: ;</PL.1>
<PL.2>Room: A;</PL.2>
<PL.3>Bed: NAH;</PL.3>
<PL.4>Group: 195;</PL.4>
```

I know my sub string is wrong, but I'm not sure of the correct way to pin point certain points. Examples that I've seen aren't calling a variable and usually only separates two things, so I'm having a hard time with the concept of breaking out more than two items.

**Current Results by XSLT:**

```
<PL.1>Wing:</PL.1>
<PL.2 />
<PL.3> 195;</PL.3>
<PL.4 />
```

Comment: See [split function in xslt 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7425071/205233) and related questions.

Comment: You should specify which version of XSLT this is. String handling in XSLT 2.0 is much more flexible than in 1.0.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKay. I've edited the title and tags to include 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a recursive template like in this XSLT-1.0 solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/root">                        <!-- Adapt to your real conditions -->
    <xsl:call-template name="NextStr">
      <xsl:with-param name="str" select="Location" /> <!-- Change to //Location if appropriate -->
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="NextStr"> 
    <xsl:param name="str" />
    <xsl:param name="cnt" select="1" />
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space($str)">
      <xsl:element name="{concat('PL.',$cnt)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(concat(substring-before($str,';'),';'))" />
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:call-template name="NextStr">
        <xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring-after($str,';')" />
        <xsl:with-param name="cnt" select="$cnt + 1" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This stylesheet derives the `PL.x` element names from a counter passed to the named template `NextStr`. You could remove the trailing `;` by removing the respective `concat(...)` from the expression.

**Output is:**

```
<PL.1>Wing: ;</PL.1>
<PL.2>Room: A;</PL.2>
<PL.3>Bed: NAH;</PL.3>
<PL.4>Group: 195;</PL.4>
```

Comment: This worked perfect for my situation, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<PL.1>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(//Location, ' ; Room:')" />
</PL.1>
<PL.2>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(//Location, ';Bed:')" />
</PL.2>
<PL.3>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(//Location, ';Group:')" />
</PL.3>
<PL.4>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(//Location, ';Group:')" />
</PL.4>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="Location">
        <xsl:variable name="a" select="substring-before(.,' Room')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="b" select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'Wing: ; '), ' Bed')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="c" select="substring-before(substring-after(.,' Room: A; '),' Group')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="d" select="substring-after(.,'NAH; ')"/>
        <PL.1>
            <xsl:value-of select="$a"/>
        </PL.1>
        <PL.2>
            <xsl:value-of select="$b"/>
        </PL.2>
        <PL.3>
            <xsl:value-of select="$c"/>
        </PL.3>
        <PL.4>
            <xsl:value-of select="$d"/>
        </PL.4>
    </xsl:template>
Use this code
```