# Split variables separated by a comma, and perform an action on each

Tags: visual-studio, xslt-1.0

I am using XSLT v1.0 and running it through Microsoft Visual Studio.

I have data (which will be different in every node) but is structured like this:

```
<ItemGroupData ItemGroupOID="DDG4">
   <ItemDataString ItemOID="DDLOCC" AuditRecordID="AR.8452551">5,8,9,2,3</ItemDataString>
   <ItemDataString ItemOID="DDLOCL" AuditRecordID="AR.8452551">1,7</ItemDataString>
   <ItemDataString ItemOID="DDLOCR" AuditRecordID="AR.8452551">1</ItemDataString>
</ItemGroupData>
```

There can be any number of values separated by commas in each of the 3 fields.

I am trying to split the data so I can work with each individual integer, and have tried the method suggested by Dimitre Novatchev here: [split function in xslt 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425071/split-function-in-xslt-1-0), but it keeps giving me the error:

> "'template' is not a recognized extension element. An error occurred at (0,0).".

The new split/mark templates I created are inside my overall template, which is being used to convert my XML to a CSV file.

Can I have a template within a template? Or do I need to define it outside the main template? Bit of a N00b with XML so any help would be greatly appreciated.

My new templates (note the `processedItem` bit has been simplified for demonstration purposes):

```
    <xsl:template match="mark">
      <xsl:variable name="vrtfSplit">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:for-each select="ext:node-set($vrtfSplit)/*">
      <processedItem>
        <xsl:if test="$varLOCOID='DDLOCL'">
          <xsl:value-of select="current() * 100"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$varLOCOID='DDLOCC'">
          <xsl:value-of select="current() * 10"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$varLOCOID='DDLOCR'">
          <xsl:value-of select="current() * 150"/>
        </xsl:if>
      </processedItem>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" name="split">
      <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
      <xsl:if test="string-length($pText) > 0">
        <item>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($pText, ','), ',')"/>
        </item>

        <xsl:call-template name="split">
          <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, ',')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: What is the expected result of transforming the given example XML? IOW, what exactly do you mean by "work with each individual integer"?

Comment: Its not easy to show becuase my actual XML is much more complicated, but each `DDLOCx` has a code-list at the bottom of the XML sheet and I use the integers to lookup the text meaning of each. For now, if I can get the output to work with just multiplying each of the integers it's trivial to modify the code to translate the integers as I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/ItemGroupData">
    <output>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ItemDataString">
    <items>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-and-process">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
            <xsl:with-param name="factor">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="@ItemOID='DDLOCL'">100</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="@ItemOID='DDLOCC'">10</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="@ItemOID='DDLOCR'">150</xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:with-param>               
        </xsl:call-template>
    </items>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize-and-process">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="factor" select="1"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
    <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
    <item>
        <xsl:value-of select="$token * $factor"/>
    </item>
    <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-and-process">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="factor" select="$factor"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input XML, the result will be:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <items>
    <item>50</item>
    <item>80</item>
    <item>90</item>
    <item>20</item>
    <item>30</item>
  </items>
  <items>
    <item>100</item>
    <item>700</item>
  </items>
  <items>
    <item>150</item>
  </items>
</output>
```

---

P.S. No, a template cannot be a child of another template.

Comment: thanks, this looks very helpful. I'm a little confused on how calling templates and the match argument work. Do you know of any good recources to help me understand it? Or are you able to clarify it for me? My main template is `match="/"` but I don't understand what that means exactly

Comment: I am mostly self-taught and thus not a good source for learning materials. When in doubt, I refer to the W3C recommendations for [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/) and [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116). But there are many tutorials and books out there. And many examples here on SO.