# wso2 split a string and iterate values

Tags: xml, wso2, wso2-esb

What would be the best solution the split a string with ',' delimiter and iterate all values in wso2 ?

Can it be done in one time ? Or I have to store values in an array and then iterate ?

Sample : `$ctx:keys = "key1,key2,key3,key4,key5"`

Wanto to iterate simply those values and print

```
key1
key2
key3
key4
key5
```

I know it would be simple in any other language but in wso2 it seems to be a pain to do. Any simple way to do what I want ?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with the script mediator, But WSO2 is encouraging more not to use script mediator most of the times. Therefore, with a class mediator is could be very easily achieve.

[Please refer the WSO2 documentation.](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Class+Mediator)

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight way to do this... I think the easiest way to do this, is use ScriptMediator, like this:

```
<script language="js">
     var sample = mc.getProperty('keys').split(',');
     for(var s in sample) {
         java.lang.System.out.println(sample[s]);  
         mc.getServiceLog().info('k: ' + sample[s]);
     }
</script>
```

If i remember in linux, the java.lang.System may not work, so you can use the Loging for just print.
Or maybe you can use xslt mediator following this topic: [split function in xslt 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425071/split-function-in-xslt-1-0/7425600#7425600)