# Need help to replace tokenize with XSLT 1.0 (1.1)

Tags: xml, foreach, xslt-1.0, tokenize, calculation

I'm working on a script, that allows me to translate table columns with a fixed width to columns with a percentage distribution (coming from some PDF production and adapting for HTML output).
I worked out a solution that is doing exactly what I want it to do, but I just found out, that the engine of our CCMS only supports XSLT 1.1.
The script relies on the tokenize() function to extract and recalculate the widths of those columns (varying number of them, too).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- default templates with context generation -->
    <xsl:template match="*[not(child::* | text())]" priority="1">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*" priority="-10">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="comment() | processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node[@class[.='UniversalTextNode']]/table-container/table">
        <table>
            <xsl:attribute name="type">fixed</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="hsdl-percent">
                <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(@hsdl-cm, '\s+')[normalize-space()]">
                    <xsl:variable name="wert" select="number(.)"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="100 div 140 * $wert * 10"/>
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:attribute>
           <xsl:copy-of select="./*"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the script in question.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<node class="MultiLangRoot" type="MultiLang">
    <node class="MultiLangAspect">
        <node xml:space="preserve">
            <node class="InfoType05" type="TextNode">
                <node class="InfoType05" type="TextNode">
                    <node class="InfoType05" type="TextNode">
                        <node class="UniversalTextNode" type="TextNode">
                            <table-container type="header">
                                <table type="scaled" hsdl-cm="3.50 10.50">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th colspan="2">
                                                <p>Table header stuff</p>
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <p>Some paragraph</p>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <p>Some paragraph</p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </table-container>
                        </node>
                    </node>
                </node>
            </node>
            <node class="InfoType01" type="TextNode">
                <node class="InfoType12" type="TextNode">
                    <node class="UniversalTextNode" type="TextNode">
                        <table-container type="header">
                            <table type="scaled" hsdl-cm="7.0 1.75 1.75 3.5">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>
                                            <p>Some header</p>
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            <p>Some header</p>
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            <p>Some header</p>
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            <p>Some header</p>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <p>Some text</p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p>Some text</p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p>Some text</p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p>Some text</p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </table-container>
                    </node>
                </node>
            </node>
        </node>
    </node>
</node>
```

Sample XML (the original is way more complex).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<node class="MultiLangRoot" type="MultiLang">
    <node class="MultiLangAspect">
        <node xml:space="preserve">
            <node class="InfoType05" type="TextNode">
                <node class="InfoType05" type="TextNode">
                    <node class="InfoType05" type="TextNode">
                        <node class="UniversalTextNode" type="TextNode">
                            <table-container type="header">
                                <table type="scaled" hsdl-cm="3.50 10.50 ">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th colspan="2">
                                                <p>Table header stuff</p>
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <p>Some paragraph</p>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <p>Some paragraph</p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </table-container>
                        </node>
                    </node>
                </node>
            </node>
            <node class="InfoType01" type="TextNode">
                <node class="InfoType12" type="TextNode">
                    <node class="UniversalTextNode" type="TextNode">
                        <table-container type="header">
                            <table type="fixed" hsdl-percent="50 12.5 12.5 25 ">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>
                                            <p>Some header</p>
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            <p>Some header</p>
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            <p>Some header</p>
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            <p>Some header</p>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <p>Some text</p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p>Some text</p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p>Some text</p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p>Some text</p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </table-container>
                    </node>
                </node>
            </node>
        </node>
    </node>
</node>
```

This is the expected result.

I've tried to wrap my head around the issue, but came up with nothing. The whole loop and recalculation completely relies on tokenize() to work the way it does. If someone could give me at least a pointer to how to tackle the whole thing, I'd really appreciate it.
Please ignore anything like the trailing spaces written to the attribute - the script is still work in progress, but I really need to tackle the basics first.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to all commenters and links provided, I could work out a solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<!-- default templates with context generation -->
<xsl:template match="*[not(child::* | text())]" priority="1">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*" priority="-10">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="comment() | processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="node[@class[.='UniversalTextNode']]/table-container/table">
    <table>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">fixed</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="hsdl-percent">
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@hsdl-cm"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:attribute>
       <xsl:copy-of select="./*"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' '"/>
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:if test="$token">
            <xsl:value-of select="100 div 140 * number($token) * 10"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: There is no such thing as XSLT 1.1, available XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: That's the information I received from our CCMS supplier, which I didn't double-check.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky: there seems to be that version: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt11/ but advised not to use

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7425600/3710053

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed, historically the XSLT 1.1 was never released, and eventually renamed as 2.0. See it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT

Comment: @Gorly Some XSLT 1.0 processors support tokenize as an extension function. Please identify your processor - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Despite its lack of full official status, XSLT 1.1 definitely is a thing. There are processors that support it and will behave differently if you tag your stylesheet as `version="1.1"`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k sadly I cannot do that, as the whole transformation process is going on in the background of some CCMS "render engine" as I would put it. So, no idea what exactly they are using. Even their support guys had to check with their developers on which version of XSLT is even supported. I'm already happy, I am able to use XSLT at all.

Comment: @Gorly If you (or they) are able to run **any** XSL transformation on the engine, then there should be no problem identifying the processor using the code in the answer I linked to in my previous comment. In any case, you can always use a pure XSLT 1.0 solution as the ones I or Siebe Jongebloed pointed to. It's just more work that way.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I managed to throw a working XSLT 1.0 together with all the various bits you guys provided. Thanks for all your efforts :)